# Anchor tags remain underlined on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, anchor

I am trying to disable my anchor tags from being underlined when hovered over. I have added `text decoration: none;` to my .scss file like so:

```
$font-family-serif: 'Nixie One';
$font-family-base: $font-family-serif;
@import "bootstrap";
//@import "bootstrap-sprockets";

//TB Navbar overrides to change the color scheme
$bgDefault      : #ffffff;
$bgHighlight    : #ffffff;
$colDefault     : #8587f1;
$colHighlight   : #4e5aff;
.navbar-default {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: $bgDefault;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
  text-decoration: none;
```

Also when I look at the web page, it seems to compute the rule correctly:

[image: Why is it still underlined?]

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar-default {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: $bgDefault;
  border-color: $bgHighlight;
  text-decoration: none;  
  a
  {
    text-decoration: none; 
    &:hover{
       text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the issue was that I just had to specify the the a tag: `a {text-decoration: none;}` within my scss file instead of just setting it for the class.